# create web app with php and docker

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I have the following `DOCKERFILE`:

```
FROM php
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone https://github.com/marcosh/webinthemiddle.git
EXPOSE 80
CMD php -S localhost:80 webinthemiddle/index.php
```

that I would like to use to create a very basic app with php.

I build the image using `sudo docker build -t marcosh/webinthemiddle .`
  and then I tried running the container using

```
sudo docker run -d -P marcosh/webinthemiddle
```

or

```
sudo docker run -d -P marcosh/webinthemiddle php -S localhost:80 webinthemiddle/index.php
```

Then I checked with `sudo docker ps` to which port was mapped the port 80 of the container and browser to `localhost:#PORT#`, but I found nothing there...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Two things will be helpful for you to debug this:

1. When debugging problems like this, start by running the container in the foreground interactively and with a TTY (`-i` and `-t` respectively). Your command would be something like `sudo docker run -i -t -P marcosh/webinthemiddle php -S localhost:80 webinthemiddle/index.php`.
2. Next, in the Docker container world, `localhost` is local to the container (not your host). Since the container is only listening on `localhost`, requests from other IP addresses (such as your host) won't get to the socket. You will want to listen on `0.0.0.0:80`.

Comment: I tried to use the -i and -t options you are suggesting. This starts immediately the PHP script and does not allow me to interact with the machine. Using sudo docker ps I see that the COMMAND is "php -S localhost:80"  and PORTS is "0.0.0.0:49156->80/tcp". Doesn't this mean that the port 80 of the container is mapped to the port 49156 of my physical machine (to be found on http://localhost:49156)?

Comment: It means port 49146 is mapped to port 80 on the container IP address. However, the container isn't listening on that IP address, it is listening on localhost. You will need to listen on all IP addresses so external connections can get to the mapped port. Your host, as far as the container is concerned, is an external connection, not a local one.